bitbucket to gitlab mirror - pull request data
I'm migrating from bitbucket to gitlab. First, I want to setup a mirror in gitlab and continue using bitbucket for some time. As a 2nd step, move the development to gitlab and stop mirror.
Gitlab initial "project import" option imports "pull requests" metadata as well, but if I use "mirroring" option to "pull" subsequent updates from bitbucket, would that sync "pull requests" data as well? This is not clearly mentioned in Gitlab documentation.
If not, any ideas to achieve that?
thank you in advance!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
